# Which logging pattern is better in TIBCO BWCE-Open Shift eco system

Tags: elk, tibco, tibco-business-works

we are planning to migrate to TIBCO BWCE on Red Hat OpenShift, can you suggest which logging pattern is most suitable.

TIBCO CLE server : send all BWCE app logs to CLE EMS and then to Database. (BWCE --> EMS --> DB)

Logging in ELK via CLE client/EMS: Send all app logs to Logstack using EMS (BWCE --> EMS --> Logstack(ELK) )

Logging in ELK via CLE client/Kafka: Send all app logs to Logstack using Kafka (BWCE --> Kafka --> Logstack(ELK))

Logging in ELK via file logging: Send all app logs to Logstack using file logging (BWCE --> file(log4j) --> Logstack(ELK))

NOTE: We may use EMS for normal application/services requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Logging in ELK via CLE client/EMS: Send all app logs to Logstack using EMS (BWCE --> EMS --> Logstack(ELK) )

Comment: BWCE --> EMS --> ELK is your answer, why BWCE (file log4j) --> FilePulgin --> ELK(4th option) is not your choice ? There is dependency with EMS always for logging as per your preferred approach.

Comment: there is a vulnerability with log4j.  you may use EMS for normal application/services requirement so you can use the ems server

Comment: you can explore on power Bi as well for logging part.